# Stata Create panel dataset with two dataframes, no common variable

Tags: dataframe, merge, stata, panel

I am creating a city-by-day panel from scratch, but I'm having trouble balancing and filling in the data. Every city needs to have an observation every day between 01jan2000 and 31dec2019, my variable of interest is a dummy variable recording whether or not an event took place on that day in that city.
My original dataset only recorded observations if event == 1, and I managed to fill in time gaps using tsfill, but I can't figure out how to balance the data or extend it to start on 01jan2000 and 31dec2019. I need every date and city because eventually it will be merged with data that uses that sample period.

My current approach is to create a balanced & filled in panel and then merge the event data using the date it took place. I have a stata df containing the 7,305 dates, and another containing the 273 cityid's I'm observing. Is it possible to generate a new df that combines these two so all 273 cities are observed every day? essentially there will be 273 x 7,304 observations, no variables of interest.

Any help figuring out how to solve the unbalanced issue using either of these approaches is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Without a data example this is hard to definitively answer, but I believe you want the `cross` command: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dcross.pdf

Comment: I don't follow this easily either. If I guess correctly `merge` will do what you are trying to do directly. There is no need to create a dataset of the same size and shape before the `merge`.